# Order data from several very different SQL tables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I need to echo and order data from several different SQL tables. I cannot use UNION as all the tables are very different (there are 6). I have ordered each individual table by timestamp but need to order them all by timestamp so the most recent event from all the tables is at the top of the echo.

Is there a simple php solution or an AJAX or jquery solution?

Here's my current code:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT * FROM news 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM feature ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 2
")or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){echo'News: <a     href="index.html">'.$row['title'].'</a><br>' ;}

?>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT * FROM members WHERE artist='Y'
ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 2
")or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){echo'New Artist: <a href="artists/artist.php?    artist='.$row['artistname'].'">'.$row['artistname'].'</a><br>' ;}

?>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT  * FROM gigs 
 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 2
")or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){echo'New Gig: <a href="artists/gigs.php?     artist='.$row['artistname'].'">'.$row['gigname'].' + '.$row['artistname'].'</a><br>' ;}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly execute a `.sort()` function with PHP on the returned timestamps -

> This function sorts an array. Elements will be arranged from lowest to highest when this function has completed.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Gather all of your data together, query by query and push them into one singular array,  then perform the sort & reverse or better yet [Darhazer's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968933/order-data-from-several-very-different-sql-tables#comment14323483_10968957) and use `.rsort()` (reverse sort) to manipulate your data in to (reverse) sequential order.

Comment: I need to order them from most recent to oldest. This would not work

Comment: Um... why ever not?  You can simply sort them and then execute an `array_reverse()`

Comment: Aha genius. I'm new to all this coding malarkey do thankyou

Comment: insead of sort() and array_reverse() you can use rsort()

Comment: This doesn't work. Please look at the code that i've added to the question.

Comment: I don't see you implementing my suggestion...

Comment: How can you push them all into one array? I tried this earlier but im obviously doing the wrong thing as it just came up with an error

Comment: @jac - [pushing elements onto an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) is not the kind of thing you need to ask people here about - we can't teach you how to program, [you'll have to come with *some* basics.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/172936)